# Why does the calendar app require access to my emails?

Tags: calendar, permission, gmail, accounts, google-calendar

I recently ran an update to Mojave 10.14.4, and following this update, I was prompted by "Internet Accounts" to re-authorise access to my Google account.

[image]

Notice that I only wish to syncrhonise Calendars and Notes in this panel, and **not** my Mail or Contacts. My concern is that, when I proceed to opening Safari and enter my credentials to authorise access, this is what the permission request looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the request includes full access to my email account. I have tried disabling the synchronisation of my Notes, but this does not seem to change the request.

It would appear then, that following the update to Mojave 10.14.4, "macOS" requests a blanket permission to my Google account regardless of my sync preferences. I would like to know why that is, and if there is any way to only give access to what I would like to sync, and nothing more.

Comment: Either macOS requests all permissions no matter what you select or Calendar reads emails to add events to your calendar automatically.

Comment: @JBis Surely the latter should be optional though? I would also assume that this would be a feature of the Mail app / mail client instead, which would require access to the calendar data, not the other way around...

Answer (score 1):

A Google account, whether added for Contacts, Calendars, Emails, or all of the above, is added the same way and requests permissions for all three. You then enable or disable them on the settings panel you see in the background.

It will not interact with your email if you leave the Mail checkbox off

Comment: So you are saying that regardless of my sync preferences, Apple requires full access to my Google account. Sources?

Comment: @Sheljohn: No - at least they'd best not. But I do think they (Apple) over-reach more than just a little. Like Microsoft, Apple "reads your mail for you", and posts up notifications for things it finds in your inbox. For example, I get "reminders" from Microsoft and Apple when I (for example) receive confirmation of a flight reservation from an airline. This is because Microsoft provides my mail service, and I read it with Outlook for Mac. Likewise Apple posts the same notices through its Calendar app, but this is only because I've been too lazy to remove my credentials from Apple's mail app.

Comment: @Seamus That is wrong, in the sense that it only occurs when you check the Mail box in System Preferences, as I said above.

Comment: @Sheljohn I don't have a source other than that they ask you to sign in before asking you what services you want, therefor they always ask for the same permissions.

Comment: @EzekielElin: I won't argue with you. I'm only saying what I've observed on my system: I get notifications from the "Calendar" app about "events" such as flights I've booked. It does this even though I have not used Apple's "Mail" app in over a year. If you've got an explanation for how that happens, would love to hear it.

Comment: @EzekielElin You appear to have confirmed my question, rather than answering it. Thanks, but I'm afraid that's not very helpful.

Comment: @Seamus I don't have an answer, but is it not possibly Google's doing?

Comment: @EzekielElin > It will not interact with your email if you leave the Mail checkbox off. I believe this is a false statement. Calendar appears to be routing around in my Gmail proposing events for things in my email even though Mail is not checked. I do not want this "helpful" feature and I see no way to turn it off in Calendar or in my Google App preferences. If you want this to change, go to Google web app preferences, [Report a third-party connected site or app](https://support.google.com/accounts/contact/report_suspicious_web_app?p=report_suspicious_web_app&hl=en&product=946018238758&source

Comment: @RohanMahy Are you sure it's not google doing that? I know Google will also create suggested events based off your email, since my Gmail account (which is added to both mail and calendar) shows two suggestions for most things, one clearly from Google and the other from Mail.